# How to generate all possible 3x3 matrices with fixed first row and column with entries from 0,1,2

Tags: python, matrix, combinations, associativity

I want to fix the first row and first column of the matrices to be 0 1 2..only such matrices is to be filtered among all possible 3x3 matrices with entries from 0,1,2. Later I have to check one condition for those filtered ones. The condition is as follows:

```
i + j = a_ij (the corresponding entry of one matrix) = m , m + k = a_mk 
j + k = a_jk (entry from j th row and k th column) = n, i + n = a_in
```

I have to display only those matrices among all combinations which satisfy `a_mk = a_in`. Its more like checking associativity. Can anyone help to complete this?

```
from itertools import product
import numpy as np
m=3
n=3

x = [[list(i[x:x+m]) for x in range(0, len(i), m)] for i in product("012", repeat=m*n)]
print(len(x))
A=[]
for j in x:
  j = np.array(j)
  for i in range(3):
    if j[0][i] == i:
      if j[i][0] == i:
        A.append(j)

print(len(A))
```

So far I have been able to write so far.

Comment: What do you mean with _"`I want to fix the first row and first column of the matrices` "_? Are constant? Is the any order condition?

Comment: how do you read the conditions? could you separate them with a `-` ?

Comment: Fix in the sense that the first entry is 0, the second entry is 1, and the third entry is 2 for both the first row and column. All other entries can be from 0,1,2.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Modifyed Code

```
from itertools import product
import numpy as np

m = 3
n = 3

x = [[list(i[x:x+m]) for x in range(0, len(i), m)] for i in product("012", repeat=m*n)]

A = []
for j in x:
    j = np.array(j, dtype=int)

    # Check conditions
    condition_1 = np.all(j[0, :] == np.arange(m))
    condition_2 = np.all(j[:, 0] == np.arange(n))
    condition_3 = np.all(j[1:, :] + np.arange(m) == j[:-1, :])
    condition_4 = np.all(j[:, 1:] + np.arange(n) == j[:, :-1])
    condition_5 = np.all(j[0, :] + np.arange(n) == j[:, 0])
    
    # Check associativity condition
    associativity_condition = np.all(j[1:, 1:] == j[:-1, :-1])
    
    if condition_1 and condition_2 and condition_3 and condition_4 and condition_5 and associativity_condition:
        A.append(j)

print(len(A))
print(A)
```

Comment: please format your code properly: use triple ` (```) to open and close a block of code. Check the preview _before_ submitting the edit

Comment: ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-be3f5a55b7d0> in <cell line: 10>()
     15     condition_2 = np.all(j[:, 0] == np.arange(n))
     16     condition_3 = np.all(j[1:, :] + np.arange(m) == j[:-1, :])
---> 17     condition_4 = np.all(j[:, 1:] + np.arange(n) == j[:, :-1])
     18     condition_5 = np.all(j[0, :] + np.arange(n) == j[:, 0])
     19 

ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (3,2) (3,)

Comment: The above code is showing an error.